# get previous 2 and next 2 words of span tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

data-color="red"I want 2 words after and before span tags. 
here is my **html code:**

```
<p>This pathway has an inner and an outer wall. The pressure <span data-color="red" class="highlight">inside the</span> eye closes the tunnel.</p>
```

I want output like this=>

```
The pressure <span data-color="red" class="highlight">inside the</span> eye closes
```

**note:** attributes in span tags changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the previous and next sibling of the `.highlight` element and slice the textNodes:

```
function get(el, dir) {
        var ps = el[dir === 'prev' ? 'previousSibling' : 'nextSibling'];
        if (!ps || ps.nodeType !== 3) return '';
        var arr = ps.nodeValue.trim().split(/\s+/g);
        return dir == 'prev' 
               ? arr.slice(-2).join(' ') 
               : arr.slice(0, 2).join(' ');
    }

$('p').has('.highlight').html(function () {
    var e = $('.highlight', this).get(0);
    return get(e, 'prev') + ' ' + e.outerHTML + ' ' + get(e, 'next');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kzx6zhkg/

Comment: is there any way to avoid the `.split` so it wont fail for `<p>This pathway has an inner and an outer wall. <strong>The</strong> pressure <span data-color="red" class="highlight">inside the</span> eye closes the tunnel.</p>`?

Comment: @Sharky Thanks. Yes, in that case the function should be greedy, i.e. if the count of the previous/next words is less than 2 it extracts remaining words from the previous/next element siblings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
var elem = $('p');
var html = elem.find('span')[0].outerHTML;
var result = elem.html().match(new RegExp("(\\w+\\s+){2}" + html + "(\\s+\\w+){2}"))[0];
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s1eeL4po/1/)